# SQLServer SSRS 2008/2012

Tags: service, reporting-services, reporting

Scenario:

90 days of sales data grouped by sales person from a stored proc.

Tablix:

A single summary calc e.g. Gross Profit achieved for 30 days (sales-costs=GP)

Sparkline:

A sparkline showing GP Acheived each day for 90 days.

Question:

How is this done in SSRS?

Many thanks in advance for suggestions and advice.

Comment: You can filter out sales data which is not in 30 days range

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset looks something like this:

```
SalesPerson  Day   Sales
Person1      Day1  10
Person1      Day2  15
Person1      Day3  40
Person1      Day4  20
Person1      Day1  10
Person1      Day1  12
```

You can create a matrix report like this image:[image: Matrix groups image]

The row grouping is on SalesPerson (Employee)
The column grouping is on Day ( so will repeat for each of 90 days)

Drag a sparkline object into the last column. The trick is that you can't add a sparkline to a details row. If you need to you can change the details group so that it groups on something that differs in each row (effectively not grouping at all).

Set the sparkline properties like this : [image: Sparkline Properties Image]

So that Day is in the categories and Sales values is in the SUM Values.

Done! Easy :)

[image: Sparkline Preview]